# Apply COALESCE between multiple fields in multiple unrelated tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

We have a table that contains configuration data for our application, and a separate table that contains global configuration data for our platform. In this instance, each table has a set of two fields to coalesce, as one of the fields is a specific value and one field is more globally considered. But if neither field is set in the application table I need the global configuration data checked in a similar way. For example our application data references "questions" and a query to get the correct value will look like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(QuestionStyleDoc,StyleDoc) AS Style
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ID = 1000
```

So that for instance 1000 I retrieve the value for questions, but if not set specifically for questions I get the main value set for instance 1000. But if neither of these values are configured I have a global configuration I can check:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Table1StyleDoc,WebStyleDoc) AS Style
FROM TABLE2
WHERE [KEY] = 1
```

That contains a value to be considered for all unset Table1 applications, or if not set a truly global value. Basically, I need to return the first non-null value like

```
COALESCE(TABLE1.QuestionStyleDoc,TABLE1.StyleDoc,TABLE2.Table1StyleDoc,TABLE2.WebStyleDoc) AS Style
```

But so far, have not had any luck between attempts to `join` or `union` the data. The goal is to get this to happen in a single query to remove round trips to the database for the application.

Comment: Are both rows guaranteed to exist?

Comment: yes the rows from each table will exist. the application starts with 1000 as it is known to exist and in our platform the `[KEY]=1` always exists as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you might be after a `FULL JOIN`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.QuestionStyleDoc, t1.StyleDoc, t2.Table1StyleDoc, t2.WebStyleDoc) style
FROM (
    SELECT QuestionStyleDoc, StyleDoc
    FROM TABLE1 
    WHERE ID = 1000
) t1
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT Table1StyleDoc, WebStyleDoc
    FROM TABLE2 
    WHERE [KEY] = 1
) t2 ON 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create a scalar user defined function to get the global style. I am passing key as parameter. As you are suggesting, Key will always be 1. But, I am adding this as parameter, if you need to call the UDF for different key.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetGlobalStyle(@Key int)  
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)   
AS   
-- Returns global style 
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @ret VARCHAR(50);  
    SET @ret = (SELECT COALESCE(Table1StyleDoc,WebStyleDoc) AS Style
FROM TABLE2
WHERE [KEY] = @key)
    RETURN @ret;  
END;
```

Now, refer this UDF in your SELECT statement for every application, so don't need to repeat the code.

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(QuestionStyleDoc,StyleDoc, dbo.GetGlobalStyle(1)) AS Style
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ID = 1000
```

Comment: Although I need an inline solution for my problem, this is an excellent idea!

Comment: @MarkM, Glad that your found this answer helpful.